# ionic3 pro package android: slow app start

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

We are using Ionic Pro Packages to generate Android build.

The problem is the app initiate very slow - it takes around 35 seconds to get in to platform.ready() function. and splash screen took around 40 seconds.

After long delay it opens app - sometimes it takes more than 45 seconds. How to reduce this time? This should open in 3-4 seconds.

**Here is an output of ionic.info**

```js
dell@dell-OptiPlex-3050:~/git/bob-app$ ionic info
✔ Gathering environment info - done!

Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.6 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v10.7.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.3.0
   OS     : Linux 4.15

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

**app.component.ts contains**

```js
constructor(
  public platform     : Platform, 
  public statusBar    : StatusBar, 
  public splashScreen : SplashScreen,
  public localStorage : Storage,
  public translate    : TranslateService,
  public toastCtrl    : ToastController,
  public network      : Network) {

  //this.translate.use('en');
  this.initializeApp();
 }
 
 initializeApp() {
  var self = this;
  self.platform.ready().then(() => {
   //checkNetworkStatus function for check network
   self.checkNetworkStatus();
  
   // to hide splash screen on time
   setTimeout(() => {
    this.splashScreen.hide();
   }, 100);
   
   //comment this befour generating build
   // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
   // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
   self.statusBar.styleDefault();
   self.splashScreen.hide();
  });
  .............
  .............
```

**package.json file**

```js
{
  "name": "RBAPP",
  "version": "0.0.10",
  "author": "CCT",
  "homepage": "http://##########/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/clipboard": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.11.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.1",
    "cordova-clipboard": "^1.2.1",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-firebase": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.19",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^5.3.1",
    "firebaseui": "^2.7.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "^2.9.0",
    "ionic-select-searchable": "^2.8.1",
    "ionic2-super-tabs": "^4.2.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^5.3.8",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.11",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-firebase": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-clipboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "Product images"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

**config.xml file**

```js
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="abcd.test.android" version="0.0.16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>RBAPP</name>
    <description>RBAPP</description>
    <author email="info@#####.com" href="http://########.com/">RBAPP Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
    <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="1.1.19" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-clipboard" spec="^1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" spec="^1.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker" spec="^2.2.2">
        <variable name="PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="Product images" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.1" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

No worries, it just resolved today by implementing Ionic lazy loading!

I think Ionic lazy loading reduces app.module.ts (main module) loads, which makes app very light while loading.

This link helped: https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-3-lazy-loading/